# Python scrape website w/BeautifulSoup4 shwoing attribute error for table with class name

Tags: python, html, pandas, beautifulsoup

I am following this tutorial: https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/extracting-data-html-beautifulsoup

To download the table on this page: http://www.knapsackfamily.com/LunchBox/top.php#res

Edit:
That table appears after I click the button "List All" which is an input in a form with `action=top.php#res`.

I inspected the table:

[image: inpsect]

and it shows the table classes are either `sortable dl` or `sortable d1` so I tried them both in my script:

```
"""
get knapsack food table and table at link "more"
follow: https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/extracting-data-html-beautifulsoup
"""

import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import lxml.html as lh

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
url = "http://www.knapsackfamily.com/LunchBox/top.php#res"
#food_df = pd.read_csv(url)

#print(food_df)

page = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml")
print(soup.prettify())

food_table = soup.find("table", attrs={"class": "sortable d1"})

food_table_data = food_table.tbody.find_all("tr")

headings=[]
# get all heading 
for th in food_table_data.find_all("th"):
    headings.append(th.b.text.replace('\n', ' ').strip())

print(headings)
```

but I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get_knapsack_tables_to_csv.py", line 24, in <module>
    food_table_data = food_table.tbody.find_all("tr")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'tbody'
```

How can I fix this?
I want to scrape it rather than using some methods in Pandas because I need to access the link the last column on that page called `more` and scrape that site's English language table cells and add them as columns to the dataframe I'm trying to make.

Comment: What is your search string? In your script you don't send any query to the server.

Comment: @AndrejKesely what do you mean by search string?  I don't see one in the tutorial I followed.

Comment: On that page is search box where you can type search string and hit enter. The table is shown afterwards.

Comment: I'm sorry I hit the button "List All".  I'll update my question

Comment: I updated to include the form action.

Comment: I think I have to do something like this: http://jonathansoma.com/lede/foundations/classes/friday%20sessions/advanced-scraping-form-submissions-completed/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get data from server, use `requests.post()` with correct form data. For example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://www.knapsackfamily.com/LunchBox/top.php'
data = {
    'mode': 'list3',
    'fword1': '',
    'mode1': ' List All'
}

soup = BeautifulSoup( requests.post(url, data=data).content, 'html.parser' )

for row in soup.select('table.d1 tr'):
    tds = [td.get_text(strip=True) for td in row.select('td, th')]
    print(*tds)
```

Prints:

```
大分類 KNApSAcK 種名 学名（一般名） 詳細データ
植物  Abelmoschus esculentus Abelmoschus esculentus[okra、おくら、オクラ、秋葵、あめりかねり、アメリカネリ、おかれんこん、オカレンコン、陸蓮根] more
植物  Abelmoschus moschatus Abelmoschus moschatus、Hibiscus abelmoschus[Ambrette、Musk seed、Musk mallow、とろろあおいもどき、トロロアオイモドキ、においとろろあおい、ニオイトロロアオイ、じゃこうあおい、ジャコウアオイ、りゅうきゅうとろろあおい、リュウキュウトロロアオイ] more
動物(魚類）  Abudefduf sexfasciatus Abudefduf sexfasciatus[scissor-tail sergeant、six-barred sergeant-major、ろくせんすずめだい、ロクセンスズメダイ、六線雀鯛] more
動物(魚類）  Abudefduf vaigiensis Abudefduf vaigiensis[five banded damsefish、sergeant major、waigieu damoiselle、おやびっちゃ、オヤビッチャ] more
植物  Acacia farnesiana Acacia farnesiana[Prickly Moses、Cassie、きんごうかん、キンゴウカン、金合歓] more
動物(魚類）  Acanthocepola krusensternii Acanthocepola krusensternii[yellowspotted bandfish、あかたち、アカタチ、赤太刀] more
動物(魚類）  Acanthocepola limbata Acanthocepola limbata[blackspot bandfish、いってんあかたち、イッテンアカタチ、一点赤太刀] more
動物(魚類）  Acanthocybium solandri Acanthocybium solandri[wahoo、かますさわら、カマスサワラ、魳鰆] more
動物(魚類）  Acanthogobius flavimanus Acanthogobius flavimanus[common blackish goby、genuine goby、spiny goby、まはぜ、マハゼ、真鯊、真沙魚、ごり、ゴリ、かじか、カジカ] more

...and so on.
```

Comment: can I use `table.sortable` rather than `table.d1`?  Did you choose class `d1` for any specific reason?

Comment: @webNoob13 You can use `table.sortable.d1` that will select `<table>` with class sortable AND d1.